# How do I select a child node?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I'm able to load an XML file that includes the following nodes in it. I'm able to get to this section of the Nodes by using the GetElementsByTagName. However, I can't seem to find the correct syntax to get the child node. I'm looking to only get the current Crewbase.

Using the following code I get the error "object not set to an instance of an object". From my research it seems as though this should work so I must be missing something simple but I'm just not seeing it.

XML section

```
<Bid>
 <Current>
    <Crewbase>DFW</Crewbase>
    <EquipmentGroup></EquipmentGroup>
 </Current>
 <Next>
    <Crewbase></Crewbase>
    <EquipmentGroup></EquipmentGroup>
    <EffectiveDate/>
 </Next>
</Bid>
```

Code:

```
XmlNodeList nodesCrewMember = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Bid");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodesCrewMember)
{
    var crewBase = node.SelectSingleNode("/Current/Crewbase").InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Your XML does not start with `/Current`. It starts with `/Bid`.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with a colleague and we found this to work. I tried something similar but didn't have two forward slashes at the beginning. The two starting slashes was the key.

```
var crewBase = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Bid/Current/Crewbase").InnerText;
```

Comment: You need to read up on the basics of XPath. Banging on it until it works is not a strategy.